# Cannot move out of `client`, a captured variable in an `FnMut` closure

Tags: rust, closures

I know that this question is asked a lot, but even with reading the other replies, I still don't know what to do to solve my problem.

I am using the mastodon-async crate to process events from a mastodon user timeline. For specific events, I want to send a part to a mqtt topic.

I am following this [example](https://github.com/dscottboggs/mastodon-async/blob/main/examples/log_events.rs)

This is how my code is right now :

```
use std::thread;
use std::time::Duration;

use anyhow::{anyhow, Result};
use futures_util::TryStreamExt;
use log::{info, warn};
use mastodon_async::helpers::toml;
use mastodon_async::Mastodon;
use mastodon_async::prelude::{Event, Status};
use rumqttc::{AsyncClient, EventLoop, MqttOptions, QoS};

async fn get_mastodon_data() -> Result<Mastodon> {
    if let Ok(data) = toml::from_file("weaselbot-mastodon.toml") {
        Ok(Mastodon::from(data))
    } else {
        Err(anyhow!("Mastodon doesn't seems to have been registered, please execute the register command !"))
    }
}

fn process_weasel_toot(status: Status) -> Result<String> {
    if !status.media_attachments.is_empty() {
        for attachement in &status.media_attachments {
            match &attachement.remote_url {
                Some(url) => {
                    let url = url.clone();
                    return Ok(url);
                }
                None => warn!("can't find remote url !"),
            }
        }
    } else {
        warn!("status without any attachments");
    }

    Err(anyhow!("Status can't be processed for media"))
}

async fn evt(mut eventloop: EventLoop) {
    while let notification = eventloop.poll().await {
        match notification {
            _ => ()
        }
    }
}

pub async fn mastodon_run() -> Result<()> {
    let mastodon = get_mastodon_data().await?;
    let stream = mastodon.stream_user().await?;


    let mut mqttoptions = MqttOptions::new("mastodon", "127.0.0.1", 1883);
    mqttoptions.set_keep_alive(Duration::from_secs(5));

    let (client, eventloop) = AsyncClient::new(mqttoptions, 10);
    // process eventloop
    thread::spawn(move || evt(eventloop));

    info!("Waiting for Mastodon events...");
    stream.try_for_each(|event| async move {
        match event {
            Event::Update(status) => {
                info!("found update event !");
                match process_weasel_toot(status) {
                    Ok(url) => {
                        info!("Found url {}", url);
                        client.publish("mastodon", QoS::AtLeastOnce, false, url);
                    }
                    _ => (),
                };
            }
            _ => (),
        }
        Ok(())
    }).await?;

    Ok(())
}


#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<()>
{
    mastodon_run().await
}
```

My dependencies :

```
[dependencies]
log = "0.4.17"
anyhow = "1.0.69"
toml = "0.5.11"
rumqttc = "0.20.0"
tokio = { version = "1.26.0", features = ["macros", "rt-multi-thread"] }
futures-util = "0.3.25"
mastodon-async = { version = "1.1.0", features = ["toml", "mt"] }
```

The compilation error :

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `client`, a captured variable in an `FnMut` closure
  --> src/main.rs:59:41
   |
54 |       let (client, eventloop) = AsyncClient::new(mqttoptions, 10);
   |            ------ captured outer variable
...
59 |       stream.try_for_each(|event| async move {
   |  _________________________-------____________^
   | |                         |
   | |                         captured by this `FnMut` closure
60 | |         match event {
61 | |             Event::Update(status) => {
62 | |                 info!("found update event !");
...  |
66 | |                         client.publish("mastodon", QoS::AtLeastOnce, false, url);
   | |                         ------
   | |                         |
   | |                         variable moved due to use in generator
   | |                         move occurs because `client` has type `rumqttc::AsyncClient`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
...  |
73 | |         Ok(())
74 | |     }).await?;
   | |_____^ move out of `client` occurs here

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0507`.
```

The mastodon-async crate use the try_stream from future-utils, and I tried to use something else than try_for_each, like a fold method that I saw could solve my problem, but I didn't find how to make it works.

Comment: Please include the full compiler output. We have no idea which line of code is causing the problem. The compiler will tell you which line it is.

Comment: It's near impossible for us to guess all the things you use correctly (`mastodon`, `AsyncClient`, `mqttoptions`, ...). So please to make it possible for us to help you efficiently, read through [mre] and provide one.

Comment: Oh, yes, indeed, I am sorry, I do that as soon as possible.

Comment: There, @cdhowie, (and cafce25), I have edited my question to. Sorry for my mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so finally I found what I needed to do : *just* remove the `move` keyword from the `try_for_each` method invocation.